# Стиль изложения в исторических книгах

Tags: стилистика

У нас как-то возник один спор. Дело в том, что я являюсь автором исторического романа и вообще пишу на эту тему. И, передавая речь героев, я пишу современным языком. Нет, конечно, не употребляю сугубо современные словечки, но пишу так, как мы говорим в обычной жизни, а не излагаю речи героев высокопарными фразами или каким-нибудь гекзаметром. А моя редактор считает, что надо именно так. Но мне кажется, что "осовременивая" речь героев, мы приближаем их к нам (или нас — к ним). Ведь в те, древние, времена их манера говорить воспринималась так, как для нас современная.
А что вы скажете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полностью с Вами согласен, хотя для придания исторического колорита отдельные словечки, фразы, свойственные описанному времени, вполне уместны в историческом романе. Главное - не переборщить, иначе читатель споткнется на трудно понимаемых фразах и не станет читать книгу.

Answer (score 1):

Это вопрос для литературных критиков, лучше где-нибудь на литературном спрашивать...

Личное мнение. Ерундой вы занялись с редактором. Писать надо так, чтобы это читалось и соответствовало авторской задумке. Синхронизация речи - прием, конечно мощный, но никакими инструкциями не прописанный. Эдак мы договоримся, что в исторических фильмах князь Игорь должен изъясняться на языке Бояна, а в военных - Штирлиц говорить только на мекленбургском диалекте.

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже так думаю! Когда герои исторических романов говорят заунывно-пафосно-высокопарными фразами, они выглядят картонными и неживыми. Равно, как и не люблю, когда иллюстрации в таких книгах стилизуют под каноны описываемого времени. Хочется видеть живых людей и читать о них.